# Как скрыть лого на главной странице Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Как скрыть название только на одной странице (главной)?
Сайт http://n67550w2.beget.tech/
Имеется в виду название `From Lakki House` слева в меню.

Comment: Лого может быть разное, например фавикон, картинка и.т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте в файл style.css

```
.home h1.site-title {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, получилось!

Answer (score 0):

Замените

```
<h1 class="site-title">
    <a href="http://n67550w2.beget.tech/ru/" rel="home">From Lakki House</a>
</h1>
```

На

```
<h1 class="site-title" style="display:none;">
    <a href="http://n67550w2.beget.tech/ru/" rel="home">From Lakki House</a>
</h1>
```

Comment: Это скроет лого на всех страницах, а мне надо скрыть только на главной.

Comment: Нет, просто измените `html` на главной странице.

Comment: Сделала, как вы сказали. Пропало на всех страницах. Этот фрагмент кода находится в файле index.php. А главная страница у меня другой файл - Шаблон страницы «Front Page» (page-templates/page_front-page.php). Может его надо было редактировать?

Comment: Вот содержимое страницы «Front Page»: http://prntscr.com/fff4t6

Comment: Скиньте где именно вы изменяли в index.php

Comment: Ой, извиняюсь, не index, а header.php. Скриншот: http://prntscr.com/ffffcq

Comment: для index.html создайте отдельный сss файл и подключите его. Затем в этом файле напишите `.site-title {display:none;}`

Comment: У меня нет файла index.html, есть только index.php, но я там ничего не разберу: http://prntscr.com/ffgfxz

Comment: Добавьте на верх index.php `<style>.site-title {display:none;}</style>`